# Creating a custom menu using a layout inflator, how do I reference each component?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

This is the item I'm inflating:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_border"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Account name"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Balance: £61.43"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I'm inflating it using the following code:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearL);

view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent,false);
parent.addView(view);
```

Say if I inflated the following item three times, to create three menu items - how would I reference each item individually?

For example, if I wanted to change the text of the Account name in the first item of the menu, how would I reference that it's in the first item of the menu, instead of the second or third?

Comment: the linearL is the layout from xml file ?

Comment: @aurelianr The linear layout is from the main activity that I'm inflating the menu item into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Say if I inflated the following item three times, to create three menu
>   items - how would I reference each item individually?

Use `parent.getChildCount()` and `parent.getChildAt()` for accessing Views from any  `R.layout.menu_item` layout like:

Add layout multiple times:

```
//First time
parent.addView(view);
//Second time
parent.addView(view);
```

Get first added `R.layout.menu_item` layout view:

```
View firstView=parent.getChildAt(0);
```

In same way get other child View of `parent` layout.

Access child Views from `firstView` using :

*View id if added in xml:*

```
TextView textView=(TextView)firstView.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
```

*or using getChildAt method:*

```
TextView textView=(TextView)firstView.getChildAt(0);
```

Access other views in same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_border"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Account name"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/balance_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Balance: £61.43"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"/>

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in code you will have some thing like

```
TextView textview = (TextView)relativeLayoutFromXml.findById(R.id.balance_text_view);

textview.setText("sadsasa ");
```

If your layout is inside activity xml you should access the textview like this:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance_text_view);

 textview.setText("sadsasa ");
```

Comment: Not really what I was looking for - Maybe I was unclear. Thanks anyway :)